# How to replace string values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am trying to replace the current values in a pandas dataframe with lists created through the .split() function on the current values. Unfortunately, I keep receiving this error `TypeError: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'str'`. I have tried multiple solutions based on answers posted on this site, but I keep getting the same error message. I am confused why this is rejecting my input as it seems like a lot of other solutions involve strings with the `to_replace` parameter. If I have misunderstood the error, i am more than open to explanation. Here is the best reproducible example I can create to illustrate the issue:

This is an example set of data:

| id | file_no |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 02-3234 |
| 2 3 | 03-3453\n03-3454 |
| 4 | 00-3562 |
| 5 6 7 | 02-5563\n02-5564\n02-5565 |

I want to use `.replace` to replace these values with lists of the values like so:

| id | file_no |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 02-3234 |
| [2,3] | 03-3453\n03-3454 |
| 4 | 00-3562 |
| [5,6,7] | 02-5563\n02-5564\n02-5565 |

Code so far:

```
for id_ in table['id']:
    if len(id_.split(" ")) == 1:
        continue
    elif len(id_.split(" ")) == 2:
        id_split = id_.split(" ")
        table['id'] = table['id'].replace(id_, id_split)                               
    elif len(id_.split(" ")) == 3:
        id_split = id_.split(" ")
        table['id'] = table['id'].replace(id_, id_split)                         
    else:
        continue
```

If anyone knows what I should be doing instead of this or if I am missing something, please let me know!

Comment: You can't have one row be a list and one row be an integer.  The column must all be the same type.  `table['id'] = table['id'].str.split()` will get you a list of strings.  No loop is required.

Comment: @TimRoberts They're not integers, they're apparently strings, since he can call `split()` on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
id_ = table['id'].str.split()
table['id'] = np.where(id_.str.len() == 1, id_.str[0], id_)

# or table['id'] = table['id'].where(id_.str.len() == 1, other=id_)
```

Output:

```
>>> table
          id                    file_no
0          1                    02-3234
1     [2, 3]           03-3453\n03-3454
2          4                    00-3562
3  [5, 6, 7]  02-5563\n02-5564\n02-5565
```

Try not to use loops when you have a "vectorized alternative", especially with the `str` accessor when dealing with strings.

Comment: Thank you, works great! And thank you for showing me this vectorized alternative method! I have been just getting into data science/coding and have been using a lot of pandas and this will help going forward.

Comment: I used this method on another column and it created a few random `NaN` values that I cannot figure out what happened. For example, on the original unformatted rows the two values in the column are 8100234 and then 8124394 and one is transformed to a NaN value and the other remains at 8124394. Any idea why this might be?